# Data from two tables in view using single controller in code ignitor

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lX5P.png)

I have two tables  one Customer and second transactions
UID( User ID) and CID (Campaign ID) are common in  both tables. I want result as shown in screenshot.

My Controller contains
`public function index()
{
$result['campaigns'] = $this->campaign_logs->campaigndetails($uid); // Getting all campaigns for UID
$this->load->view( 'dashboard',$result );
}`

By this I am able to pull up campaigns but now I want all count(transactions) for each campaign in dashboard view as mentioned in screenshot.

Problem is one UID can contain many CID's and each CID contains variable transactions. how I can pass cid to pulp results.

Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: read about [MySQL sum()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) and [MySQL join()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

Comment: you need to be more specific in terms of database structure you are using.Better you create a database fiddle and provide the link.